# How to Switch Oracle jet Gantt chart RTL

Tags: oracle, oracle-jet

I am setting gantt chart direction RTL.

Gantt chart hiding row axis lables and overlap lables in timeline bar

I used below gantt chart from oracle jet cookbook.

[demo link](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=gantt&demo=valueFormats)

Here is screenshot of Switching OJET Gantt chart Direction LTR to RTL

[image]

Suggest me how to set direction?

I tried with refresh method

```
var a =document.getElementById('gantt'); 
a.dir="RTL"; 
a.refresh();
```

[Code from oracle jet Cookbook](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=gantt&demo=valueFormats)

Answer (score 0):

Without trying RTL I had a similar problem and the following fixed it....

in the html:

```
<oj-gantt.....
row-axis.rendered="[[ax]]"
...</oj-gantt>
```

In your viewModel define:

```
self.ax = ko.observable("off");
```

When you switch to RTL try setting:

```
self.ax("on");
```